# PHP MYSQL создание индекса для оператора LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

На сайте есть форма поиска FULL TEXT SEARCH, которая до сего времени использовалась по умолчанию. Я решил отказаться от неё в пользу LIKE так как результаты FULL TEXT были не удовлетворительны. Так вот, я бы хотел узнать следующее, нужно ли для этого оператора создавать какие либо индексы, для увеличения производительности и скорость, или для дополнительной оптимизации? Поиск идёт в  таблице, в двух полях.

Comment: судя по всему, [никак не задействовать индекс](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042269/how-to-speed-up-select-like-queries-in-mysql-on-multiple-columns) (eng)

Comment: *Я решил отказаться от неё в пользу LIKE так как результаты FULL TEXT были не удовлетворительны.* Вот этим вопросом и надо заняться. Судя по намерению использовать LIKE - нужно строгое соответствие, а для этого нужно указывать правильные режим и модификаторы поиска. *нужно ли для этого оператора создавать какие либо индексы, для увеличения производительности и скорость, или для дополнительной оптимизации?* Только если ищется фрагмент, с которого начинается значение поля. Для LIKE-поиска в середине значения любые индексы неприменимы.

Comment: @Akina к примеру есть заголовок "CS GO продажа", если выполнить поиск при помощи FTS, и ввести "CS", то ничего не будет найдено, что довольно неудобно.

Comment: *если выполнить поиск при помощи FTS, и ввести "CS", то ничего не будет найдено, что довольно неудобно* А настраивать поиск кто будет - Пушкин? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length

Comment: @Akina дело в том что минимальный лимит видимо уже стоит, так как иногда двухсимвольный поиск возвращает результат.

Comment: *минимальный лимит видимо уже стоит* А какой смысл гадать, почему бы просто не посмотреть? а заодно и стоп-лист почитать...

Comment: @Akina а как он может не стоять, если запрос на двух символах иногда возвращает результат?

Comment: А вы всегда ищете отдельные слова, или вам нужны так же части слов. т.е. по запросу CS должен найтись "GOCS продажа" или скажем "GO-CS". А "CSGO" и "CS-GO" ?

Comment: @Mike так же части.